# Почему "компрометировать" через Е?

Tags: орфография

Всегда был уверен, что слово "компрометировать" происходит от слова "компромисс" и именно "компромисс" является для него проверочным. Однако Ворд подчеркнул мне его, когда я написал "компромИтировать" через И, предлагая вариант через Е.
Правильно ли это и, если да, то от какого в таком случае корня происходит слово "компрометировать"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересно, что в основе слов "компромат и компромисс"с разным значением лежит латинский глагол  compromittere, который буквально означает «взаимно обещать, договориться».

КОМПРОМИСС - это соглашение, достигнутое путем взаимных уступок. Заимств. в конце XVIII в. из франц. яз., где compromis < лат. compromissum "договоренность, взаимное обещание" — от compromise "приходить к соглашению", преф. производного от promittere "обещать, сулить".

КОМПРОМЕТАЦИЯ(от франц. compromettre — портить репутацию, компрометировать)

Но как же связаны между собой такие разные значения слов, имеющих общее происхождение? Дело в том, что  сompromettre (compromittere) — дословно означает СОГЛАСИТЬСЯ на третейский суд, то есть дать возможность судить третьему лицу, передать дело на арбитраж.

Таким образом, компрометировать - это передать на суд общественности материалы, которые могут подорвать чью-либо репутацию.

Иак, мы видим, что в русском языке слова "компромет/аци/я, компромет/ирова/ть и компромисс" имеют разные корни, и буква Е в слове "компрометировать" соответствует латинскому первоисточнику.

Answer (score 3):

КОМПРОМЕТИ́РОВАТЬ, (франц. compromettre). Вредить кому-нибудь, набрасывать тень на чье-нибудь доброе имя, чью-нибудь репутацию. Компрометировать себя в глазах общества.КОМПРОМИСС, -а; м. [лат. compromissium]
Соглашение на основе взаимных уступок.
Как видите, эти слова пришли в русский из разных языков.

София, а что означает "преф'' в этом отрывке:  от compromise "приходить к соглашению", преф.

Спасибо, София.

Comment: Сompromittere - префиксальное производное от promittere, приставка com.